# Uploading zip files larger than 10mb from S3 bucket to lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

When I try to upload file from s3 bucket, I get error (Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again.)

How do I solve this. Thank you, Community!

I have npm dependencies within my .rar file that contains lambda functions for an API and I am exposing the url vi API Gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> I have npm dependencies within my **.rar file** that contains lambda
> functions for an API and I am exposing the url vi API Gateway.

Lambda supports two types of deployment packages: **container images** and **.zip file archives**:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-zip.html

So, the issue is likely that Lambda can't unzip your .rar file, in accordance with the error message, you describe.

Furthermore, be aware of the following quotas, e.g. the size of an unzipped deployment package is limited to 250 MB:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html#function-configuration-deployment-and-execution

Comment: It worked. I had used .rar instead of .zip from the beginning. Changing the extension was a mistake. Thank you, Nikolas.

Comment: I'm happy that it worked for you! :)